# why Lord krishna say that wise lament neither for the living nor for the dead?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Gita chapter  2  verse  11

> śhrī bhagavān uvācha
> aśhochyān-anvaśhochas-tvaṁ prajñā-vādānśh cha bhāṣhase
> gatāsūn-agatāsūnśh-cha nānuśhochanti paṇḍitāḥ

Meaning :The wise lament neither for the living nor for the dead.

My question :why  Lord krishna say  that wise lament neither for the living nor for the dead ?.What is the purpose of this statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Krishna is suggesting about the mortality of a Human being and asking Arjun not to be attached by the human emotions. That's why he says, "The wise lament neither for the living nor for the dead."

As you can see in further verses he explains it in more detail :

Chapter 2 verse 12:

na tvevāhaṁ jātu nāsaṁ na tvaṁ neme janādhipāḥ
na chaiva na bhaviṣhyāmaḥ sarve vayamataḥ param